# Make the scroll bar fit on different monitor resolution

Tags: css

I got stucked on my css, i want to make my scroll bar fit on diffrent monitor resoution, and i use this css

```css
div.scroll {
    width:800px;
    height:800px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

but it will show differently in the other resolution, and if I change the width or height into 100%. the scroll bar just doesnt work. the scroll bar is still there but it shows the whole table, such a waste scroll bar.

any help will be appriciated

Answer (score 1):

Try with this :
First set body style `margin:0` as :

```
body{
margin : 0;
}
```

and the div.scroll as :

```
div.scroll
{
width:800px;
height:100%;
overflow:auto;
}
```

`overflow:auto` gives a vertical scroll to your div if the content is more than the height.

Comment: almost there, but it creates a big free space in a bigger resolution

Comment: Try with set top: 200px or 300px; bottom: 0; May be free space will be reduced.

Comment: do i have to add it in the div.scroll or? its rare for me to use css, so please be bear with me, ive tried added the top and bottom stuff in div.scroll but it doesnt work

Comment: yes with div.scroll. & also try once with remove height:100% only try with top:300px; bottom: 0;  Or its better if you create a fiddle for your problem.

Comment: it works fine in the bigger resolution, but now it looks so bad in smaller one

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `min-width` and `min-height`?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="scroll">
    <p>This is the scrolling area</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.scroll
{
min-width:800px;
min-height:800px;
overflow:auto;
}

.scroll p
{
    width: 900px;
    background: #cc0000;

}
```

**Working Example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Aps83/

Not entirely clear on your desired outcome, but this will present scrollbars only when needed (small screen, content is too wide/tall to fit).